# Is it possible to add properties on custom Open Graph story?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to create custom Open Graph story that has image and properties below it. The final story would look something like this:

[Example of fitness story from Runkeeper's website](https://support.runkeeper.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/200839479/map.png)

So far I have been able to add those properties through story attachments which reads meta properties. The problem is that they only shows as text below the image.

Is it possible to create custom story with that kind of properties or is it exclusive to fitness story?

**EDIT**

I don't think that any code is relevant for the question as most of the things related to this are done through Facebook Developer Console. I have defined my own Action and Object Types to create custom Story. I have given object some properties and I have included them in story Attachments. I have created web page with meta properties to create custom story. These properties are displayed correctly in the story but only as text, not as cool array-like way as in fitness story.

So how to achieve this array-like appearance for custom story?

Meta-properties:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{app_id}" />
<meta property="fb:explicitly_shared" content="true" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="fi_FI" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="sv_SE" />
<meta property="og:url" content="{url}" />
<meta property="og:type" content="{my_own_type}" />
<meta property="og:title" content="{title}" />
<meta property="og:image" content="{image_url}" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{description}" />
<meta property="{my_own_property_1}" content="1,20" />
<meta property="{my_own_property_2}" content="16-17" />
<meta property="{my_own_property_3}" content="+30%" />
<meta property="{my_own_property_4}" content="2015-02-11T10:00:00+02:00" />
```

Comment: It should be possible, but without a code snippet it is hard to tell what your issue *really* is. Please consider editing your question and adding more details (such as a code snippet)

Comment: @derabbink See edited question